# Are there any good documentary films about the continuum hypothesis?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, set-theory, foundations

Are there any good documentary films about the continuum hypothesis? I'm looking for something slightly more serious than the usual "Cantor showed that infinity plus one equals infinity and then went bonkers" type thing. I also don't agree with the assertion that "the continuum hypothesis tells us something incredible about the fundamental incompleteness of mathematics," so I'd prefer a documentary that doesn't indulge in this sort of thing.

Comment: “Cantor showed that infinity plus one equals infinity and then went bonkers” - You are SO right! That is SUCH silly nonsense! What *really* happened is, he showed that [all infinities are equal, but some infinities are more equal than others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_Farm),... and THEN went bonkers! :-)

Comment: @Lucian, haha totally. The untold true story of Georg "Orwell" Cantor.

Comment: For better or for worse, [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1520274/) is the **only** title in **all** of IMDB whose web-page explicitly references either Cantor or his famous hypothesis. Book-wise, there's also [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_of_Mathematics).

Comment: @Lucian: The video was/is on YouTube (legally, if I recall correctly). I don't recall it being that great. In terms of books, there's a book about Cantor from these aspects. I don't remember the name right now.

Comment: [_Chaos: A Mathematical Adventure_](http://www.chaos-math.org/) (2010) and [_Dimensions_](http://www.dimensions-math.org/) (2008) by Jos Leys, Étienne Ghys, Aurélien Alvarez, et al. are excellent, [CC BY-NC-ND 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/deed.en)-licensed (i.e., free) movies about math. Continuity/discontinuity is discussed in parts of _Chaos_.